# Load data to Snowflake

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
### ESTABLISHING CONNECTION TO SNOWFALKE 

#Installing libraries
##pip install snowflake-connector-python==2.3.8

#Importing all the required libraries
import getpass
import snowflake.connector
import pandas as pd

#Getting user imputs to establish connection to snowflake

USER = input("PLEASE ENTER YOUR SNOWFLAKE USERNAME ")
PASSWORD = getpass.getpass("ENTER YOUR SNOWFLAKE PASSWORD ")


ACCOUNT = input("PLEASE ENTER YOUR SNOWFLAKE ACCOUNT NAME ")


#create snowflake database connection
conn= snowflake.connector.connect(
    user=USER,
    password=PASSWORD,
    account=ACCOUNT,
    warehouse='COHORT_XL',
    database = 'IMV_IMMUNOVACCINE_INC_DLBCL_RITUXIMAB_ANY_ANTHRACYCLINE',
    schema = 'SANDBOX'
)

cur=conn.cursor()

#Checking the conenction
cur

import pandas as pd

original = r"C:\Users\aseem.malik\Downloads\TX.csv" # <- Replace with your path.
delimiter = "," # Replace if you're using a different delimiter.

total = pd.read_csv(original, sep = delimiter)

write_pandas(conn, total, 'test')
```

The write pandas funtion is not working keeps giving the below error.

```
 Unable to find a usable engine; tried using: 'pyarrow', 'fastparquet'.
A suitable version of pyarrow or fastparquet is required for parquet support.
Trying to import the above resulted in these errors:
 - Missing optional dependency 'pyarrow'. pyarrow is required for parquet support. Use pip or conda to install pyarrow.
 - Missing optional dependency 'fastparquet'. fastparquet is required for parquet support. Use pip or conda to install fastparquet.
```

Comment: Well, did you `Use pip or conda to install ...`?

Comment: You need to install either `pyarrow` or `fastparquet` in order for `write_pandas` to be able to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please install those packages:

```
pip install pyarrow
pip install fastparquet
```

Answer (score 0):

I helped someone at my job resolve this issue, as mentioned by others the correct resolution is to install the recommended dependencies. Also, what probably caused this is pip installing the connector without the pandas library argument such as `pip install snowflake-connector-python` but what you MUST do if you are planning to use pandas is `pip install "snowflake-connector-python[pandas]"`

For more information: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-pandas